# Vertical vs Horizontal - unusual grid

Tags: image, css, responsive-design, grid

I have a layout I am trying to make it responsive.

[image]

There is a 10px gap between the images the problem I am having is making the layout responsive. It does not keep the bottom edges aligned at certain sizes because the browser trying to retain the proportion on the horizontal images.

The big vertical image is 750px by 1200px. The small ones I have made 750px by 595px which is half the height minus half the height of the gap.

Any possible solution or ideas are welcome.

Comment: Can you post a live example or a fiddle with the code?

Comment: are you open to twitter bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (working [codepen](http://codepen.io/dragosmicu/pen/jBapKK))

```
<div class="group">
  <div class="sm"></div>
  <div class="sm"></div>
</div>
<div class="lg"></div>
```

CSS

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;

    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

div {
  width: calc(50% - 5px);
  float: left;
}

.group {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.sm {
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.lg {
  height: calc(400px + 10px);
  background: green;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  div {
    width: 100%;
  } 
}
```